# Spring with Executor service

Tags: java, spring, multithreading

I am new to Spring with `ExecutorService`. Please can you confirm the code below? I have initailized `ExecutorSerive` in `@PostConstruct` method and destoryed it in the `@PreDestroy` method.Is there a need to call `shutdownNow()`. If yes, where would it be?

```
private static final int FIXED_THREAD_POOL_SIZE =3;

private static final Log LOGGER = LogFactory.getLog(HotelProgramInfoHistoryService.class);

private ExecutorService executorService;


@PostConstruct
public void initialize() throws Exception {

    if(executorService == null) {
        this.executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(FIXED_THREAD_POOL_SIZE);
    }
}

public void sendRequest(DomainSecurity security, HotelProgramInfo hotelProgramInfo) {

    try {
        ProgramInfoHistoryUpdateTask programInfoHistoryUpdateTask = new ProgramInfoHistoryUpdateTask(hotelProgramInfo);
        this.executorService.submit(programInfoHistoryUpdateTask);
    } catch (Exception exception) {
        LOGGER.error("Exception occurred while submitting update task ", exception);
    }

}

@PreDestroy
public void cleanUp() throws Exception {
    if(executorService != null)
    {
        executorService.shutdown();
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your needs. As the java-doc clearly states for the shutdown method:

```
... previously submitted
tasks are executed, but no new tasks will be accepted
```

wheras the shutdownNow tries to stop the currently running task. Trying means "best effort". The implementation of the task must cooperate to react properly on a "stop" request from the ouside (usually done by Thread.interrupt).

Neither the shutdown nor the shutdownNow waits until running tasks (threads) are really terminated. A java program only fully terminates if the last thread has terminated, not only the main thread. (well, depends on the setting of the Threads daemon flag. But since you rely on a default executor implementation you do not have this under control without providing a custom ThreadFactory, e.g. when using the ThreadPoolExecutor)